# Why is input form appending "?" when enter key is pressed?

Tags: jquery, forms, input

My site is [here:](http://bfcards.edicypages.com/) When entering text in the search input form the page refreshes and appends "?" to the url.

However, when the search link is pressed, everything works fine. Its really boggling my mind as to why it is appending "?" as I haven't included that code anywhere. The intended behavior is for it to click the link instead of refreshing the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#coolIrisSearch").keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 13) {
            $("#searchbutton").click();
            return false;
        }
    });

    doCoolIrisSearch = function() {
        cooliris.embed.setFeedURL( 'http%3A%2F%2Fpipes.yahooapis.com%2Fpipes%2Fpipe.run%3FSearch%3D'+encodeURIComponent($('#coolIrisSearch').val())+'%26_id%3D5f4545ce4062c36e4c5d9a8763b3167e%26_render%3Drss' );
        filter();
    };   
});
```

Ok found the answer. The form field is pretty strict. You can't remove the "submit" input field and change it into a link. Or else, the output will do what it was doing previously - appending "?" and the name attribute of the first input field. This is the correct version:

```
    <form name="searchForm">
    <input type="text" name="coolIrisSearch" id="coolIrisSearch" onfocus="this.value=''" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" onclick="doCoolIrisSearch();return false;" />
    </form>
```

While this version will cause the url to append "?coolIrisSearch=" and reload the page.

```
<form name="searchForm">
<input type="text" name="coolIrisSearch" id="coolIrisSearch" onfocus="this.value=''" />
</form>
```

Hope someone else finds this helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding click listeners to buttons and key things to inputs, try just listening to the `submit` event of forms.

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function() {
    doCoolIrisSearch();
    return false;
});
```

Much simpler.

**Edit:** I tried debugging your code using Chrome's excellent Web Inspector and it appears you're calling `filter` with an `id` sometimes, and without an `id` sometimes. You can fix this by changing this line:

```
document.getElementById(id).className += " active";
```

To this:

```
if(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).className += " active";
}
```

Comment: @UrBestFriend: Part of your code was throwing an exception. I edited my answer to show you how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry the site went down but I'll add that definitely. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, the site is back up. However, the problem is still not solved.

Comment: @UrBestFriend: `filter` hasn't been fixed like I showed how to do.

Comment: @icktoofay sure? I added it to all filter functions.

Comment: @UrBestFriend: Whoops, I see now. The thing is that the `if` statement should only be around that one `className += " active";` line. No other lines need to be wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

That because you forgot to add a name attribute to your input tag

```
<input name='search' type='text' />
```

try adding that

Answer (score 0):

One option is to call doCoolIrisSearch() when enter is pressed rather then causing a "click" the link

Comment: Yup, thanks for this. But it wasn't the issue. Rather the unusual appending of "?" to the url and reloading. However I found the fix.