# Submitting form with enter button in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My issue is that when I click my button, it will work properly, but if I use the enter button, it will attempt to submit the form and appends a ?var=x to the URL.

My two inputs:

```
    <input type="text" name="users" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('submitbtn').click()">
    <input type="button" name="submitbtn" onclick="showUser(users.value)">
```

You may view my source for the rest. If you put in 1 or 2 and click the button, you will get results, but if you hit enter, it will not give you results and changes the URL as I said.

http://crystalarcade.com/shoutbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839707/why-is-input-form-appending-when-enter-key-is-pressed

Comment: @Ajgreene, the answer on 5839707 displays how to use the jQuery submit event, it would be a cleaner way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using `document.getElementById` so give your button an id

like this

```
<input type="text" name="users" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('submitbtn').click()">
<input type="button" id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn" onclick="showUser(users.value)">
```

and this will work for you

Comment: AH CRAP I just noticed I put name instead of id... I'm an idiot. One sec, let me try that.

Comment: That answers it. Thanks lol. Such a simple mistake. I'll mark this as the answer once I can.

Comment: Also, for future reference. I had to change the onkeydown to: onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();event.returnValue=false;event.cancel=true;}"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you will have a form with just two input elements. With jQuery you can do something like this:

Some thing like this should get you started with, I need make a note however that this code is untested because I cannot do cross-site request using AJAX.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#username").on("keypress", function(e){
       if(e.keyCode==13){ //keyCode value of 13 is for the enter key
        $.get("getusers.php" $("#userSearchForm").serialize(), function(data){
            if(data){
              $("shoutboxtxt").text(data);      
            }                
        }, "text");
    }
  }
});​
</script>

<form id="userSearchForm">
    <input type="text" name="users" id="username" />
    <input type="button" name="submitbtn" id="submitbtn" value="Search" />
</form>

<div id="shoutboxtxt"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>​
```

Online here: http://jsfiddle.net/HwcN3/1/

Comment: Also, I need to point it out to you that you are referencing the jQuery source in you script tag but not really using it. Now would be a really good time to get started with using it. I am taking about [this](http://crystalarcade.com/shoutbox) site.

Edit: Forgot the include the link to your site.